# Картинка внутри Path

Tags: java, android, canvas

Добрый день,

Рисую на `Canvas` многогранную фигуру - это рамка для картинки.

Пример:

[image: Пример].

С помощью `Path` рисую видимую обводку картинки.
Как мне загрузить `Bitmap` внутрь рамки, чтобы с внешней стороны рамки был прозрачный цвет (цвет родительского компонента)?

Comment: плюсанул за котика)

Answer (score 2):

При помощи этого класса Я закругляю углы у всех Child View данного layout'а. Нужный `Path` рассчитывается в `onSizeChanged`. Если вы в нем создадите необходимый вам `Path`, то получите то ,что вам требуется

```
public class RoundClipLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private Path path = new Path();

    public RoundClipLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundClipLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundClipLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public RoundClipLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        path.reset();
        int left, right;
        right = w - h / 2;
        left = h / 2 + h % 2;
        RectF rectF = new RectF(left, 0, right, h);
        path.addRect(rectF, Path.Direction.CCW);
        RectF oval = new RectF(0, 0, h, h);
        path.addArc(oval, 90, 180);
        oval.set(w - h, 0, w, h);
        path.addArc(oval, -90, 180);
        path.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int save = canvas.save();
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(save);
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить обводку, попробуйте поэкспериментировать по рисованию линии по `Path` в `dispatchDraw`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение своей задачи. Благодаря сообщению [metalurgus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3997/metalurgus). Ключ к разгадке оказался в функции `canvas.clipPath(path);`

вот часть рабочего кода:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
  ...
  path.close();
  canvas.clipPath(path); 
  drawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
  drawable.draw(canvas);
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```